# Object with private default constructor returned by pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function that returns an object via a pointer argument. However the object has a private default constructor, so how can I create a variable to pass the address in?

```
class Foo {
  Foo(/*some parameters*/);
private:
  Foo();
};

void bar( Foo* foo ) {
  *foo = Foo(/*some arguments*/);
}

Foo f; //doesn't compile because default constructor is private
bar( &f );
```

The code is simplified, I can't really change `Foo` or `bar`

Comment: `#define private public #include "ClassThatHasFoo.h" #undef private` :)

Comment: Or just create a local `Foo` object that calls the public constructor of `Foo` with bogus parameters.

Comment: Unless you can change `bar()` or access to `Foo::Foo()` you're stuck. Assuming nothing is friended and thus has access to `Foo::Foo()` only `Foo` members (static or otherwise) can construct via `Foo::Foo()`. Not even derivations of `Foo` can do what you want, much less a free-function like `bar()`. You said you can't change `Foo` and can't change `bar`; that leaves only the last two lines to work with, and that ain't much if you can't use the parameterized ctor. Something tells me your "simplified" example is *over*-simplified.

Comment: So there is no way to say just create some space in memory that will fit a Foo, I'll fill it in later?

Comment: There is a way to do that, but you need to **construct** an object into that space, not just assign to it. You can't assign a new value to an object that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Not with the current implementation of bar

Comment: Which of the code is yours and which you cannot change?

Comment: How do I put my socks on after I've put my shoes on? Simple: take your shoes off.

Comment: but you can allocate space on the stack/heap using alloc/etc and then pass the address of that space in to bar, and while extremely ugly it's pretty simple. So why isn't it possible in C++ to create a variable without creating an object? In swift if you create a variable without assigning to it, the compiler will warn about an uninitialized variable, Why is it in C++ variable and object are so tightly related?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the public, non-default constructor to create the first version of the `Foo` instance, that will be re-assigned in `bar`:

```
Foo f(/*some arguments*/);
bar(&f);
```

It probably won't matter which argument values you pass, unless the move assignment operator does something special with the old values.

Yes, it seems pointless, but `Foo` has been designed so that `bar` is really inconvenient to use (or the other way round).

> So there is no way to say just create some space in memory that will fit a Foo, I'll fill it in later?

Not using `bar`. `bar` does an assignment, and an assignment requires the left hand side to be an existing object, that is in a valid state.

> So why isn't it possible in C++ to create a variable without creating an object?
>
> Why is it in C++ variable and object are so tightly related?

Because that is the way C++ has been specified. A variable is a name for an object. It is not a name for something that might be an object or might be not-an-object. And it's a good decision too. Thanks to this design, you can always rest assured, that the object named by a variable does always exist sans a bug in your program. (Reference variables are different, since they aren't an object themselves).

The issue with `Foo` and `bar` isn't a limitation of the language. The issue is bad design of `Foo` and/or `bar`.

Comment: This is indeed the only option, if `Foo` and `bar` cannot be changed

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question, because it relies on changing `bar`, but to answer this comment:

> So there is no way to say just create some space in memory that will fit a Foo, I'll fill it in later?

For objects of non-trivial types (like the `Foo` in your example) the only way to do that is *construct* a new object at that address, not assign to an existing object. You can do that with a placement new-expression:

```
void bar( Foo* foo ) {
  new (foo) Foo(/*some arguments*/);
}
```

Now instead of the address of an existing object, the argument to the function needs to be a chunk of uninitialized memory which is suitably-aligned for a `Foo` object, which you can do with the `aligned_storage` type:

```
std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Foo), alignof(Foo)>::type storage;
Foo* addr = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&storage);
bar( addr );
```

However, because you've manually started the lifetime of a `Foo` at that location, it's also your responsibility to manually end its lifetime, by explicitly invoking the destructor when you're finished with it:

```
addr->~Foo();
```

This is obviously more error-prone than relying on the compiler to construct and destroy your object automatically.

Comment: Sadly, "I can't really change Foo or bar". So this is out  of the question too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the person who had written the code for `class Foo` did not want anyone to create objects of `class Foo` using default c'tor. Instead he/she wanted to create the objects of `class Foo` using method `bar()`;

So try this:

```
class Foo {
  Foo(/*some parameters*/);
private:
  Foo();
};

void bar( Foo** foo ) {
  //*foo = Foo(/*some arguments*/);
  *foo = new Foo(/*some arguments*/);
}

Foo *f = NULL; //doesn't compile because default constructor is private
bar( &f );
```

Note:  You need to create a pointer to `class Foo i.e *f` and pass the address of this pointer. Inside method `bar()` an object of `class Foo` will get created and this object's address will be assigned to the pointer `f`.

Comment: @GillBates: In `*foo = Foo(/**some arguments/)` , nullptr is not dereferenced. Instead pointer `f` is accessed. Only mistake is assigning an object to pointer instead of assigning address of object to pointer. Which if `new Foo(/**some arguments/);` is used will resolve the issue.

Comment: Either way, it changes bar

Comment: @sameerkn whoops, I too missed that null isn't dereferenced. Pointers to pointers confuse me.